# Single quote escape in JavaScript Alert() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing some French line through `javascript alert function` and the French line looks like:

```
S'il vous plaît accepter les termes et conditions avant de procéder
```

And alert look like in page source:

```
alert('S'il vous plaît entrer une adresse email valide!');
```

[Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) is showing an error message like:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I try to escape the French line like:

```
alert('S\\'il vous plaît entrer une adresse email valide!');
alert('S\\\'il vous plaît entrer une adresse email valide!');
alert('S&quot;'&quot;il vous plaît entrer une adresse email valide!');
```

All guidelines were followed, but nothing works. So how do I fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try -

```
alert("S'il vous plaît entrer une adresse email valide!");
```

This is probably the simplest approach. Whenever you need to pass a single quote in a string, wrap it inside a double quote, and vice versa.

If you have a mix of single and double quote in a string, then wrap it inside either single quotes or double quotes, and escape the corresponding ones in the string using a single backslash -

```
alert("So she said, \"Hey!, how are you?\". I said, 'I am fine, thanks'.")
```

Comment: The simplest solution is always the best :)

Comment: What if input string contains both ' and "?

Comment: @RuslanasBalčiūnas then you would be forced to escape the string, but why complicate things needlessly?

Answer (score 5):

A single backslash.

`alert('S\'il vous plaît entrer une adresse email valide!')`

Answer (score 1):

You're not escaping correctly.

Try this:

```
alert('S\'il vous plaît entrer une adresse email valide!');
```

Answer (score 1):

use the escape sequence properly

```
alert('S\'il vous plaît entrer une adresse email valide!')
```