# Why is the alert in the following code not executed:?

Tags: javascript, php

This is part of a PHP file to connect to the MySQL database and perform CRUD operations, the 'alert' function inside 'echo' is not executed ..Why??:

```html
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
        $id = $_GET['del'];
        echo '<script> alert("The record"' . $id  .'"will be deleted");<script>';              // exit;
        mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM info WHERE id=$id");
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Address deleted!";
        header('location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: @Zeljka but he's doing the concat in PHP. which looks super confusing

Comment: because the script tag isn't evaluated after it was added by PHP

Comment: sorry I saw it,so I erased answ

Comment: You are not echo-ing the `alert...`, how it is executed as JS?

Comment: `echo '<script language="javascript">;`   the semicolon is not needed

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the header('location: index.php');
[According to PHP:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by >normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Comment: I deleted header('location: index.php'); and corrected the code as shown and no answer worked!!

Answer (score 2):

Cause of alert is not a php function so you need to echo alert in same line
in this way

echo 'alert("The record "'.$id.'"will be deleted")';

Comment: echo 'alert("The record "'.$id.'"will be deleted")';

Comment: echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo ' alert("The record"' . $id  .'"will be deleted")';
        echo ' </script>';

Answer (score 1):

Don't echo the js, just close the php tag and write js as it is

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
        $id = $_GET['del'];
        ?>
       <script>
         alert("The record <?=$id?> will be deleted");
         </script>
       <?php

        mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM info WHERE id=$id");
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Address deleted!";
        header('location: index.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Also don't use the deprecated attribute language. Use type="text/javascript" instead.

Comment: your code will ignore anything between the closing ?> and the new <?php and nothing will be executed https://stackoverflow.com/users/4004175/masivuye-cokile

Comment: Did you try the code or you are guessing @lonecoder

Comment: Yes I did. You can try it yourself. @Masivuye-Cokile

Comment: You have an error somewhere that is not related with the current question enable error reporting

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about this but i think the semicolon ( ; ) tells echo to stop there so echo just opens the script but doesn't see the rest

Try this :

```
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {

        $id = $_GET['del'];
        echo '<script language="javascript">
         alert("The record"' . $id  .'"will be deleted")
         </script>';
        // exit;
        mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM info WHERE id=$id");
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Address deleted!";
        header('location: index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like this.

```
alert("The record " + '. $id .' +" will be deleted");
```

Or you can just escape quotes like:

```
alert("The record \" '. $id .' \" will be deleted");
```

Comment: What is the use of escaping with '\'.. I did not get it?

Comment: You can check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19271551/9128954
Long story short, your code looks like:
alert("The record " 3 " will be deleted")
Without using escape character you can't write quotes inside quotes 
alert("you need to use escape for writing quotes \" this quote will be ignored by alert")

Comment: This should be work: alert("The record  '. $id .'  will be deleted");

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly echo . Try this instead

```
echo '<html><script> alert("The record"' . $id  .'"will be deleted")<script></html>';
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems reasonable but unfortunately did not show the alert box. When I place : echo 'alert("hello");';  outside the if(..){..} block it will show.

Comment: @lonecoder try by alerting some dummy string. See if it works. Also if alert works outside the if() then there is a chance that $_GET['del'] is not set. So i suggest you to first check that by trying to echo some string inside the if() without the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing stuff and then redirecting is not really working.
Maybe you want to echo the message instead and then the user can click an ok button to get redirected to the index page.

```
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
  $id = $_GET['del'];
  mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM info WHERE id=$id");
  $_SESSION['message'] = "Address deleted!";
  echo '<script>';
  echo 'function backToIndex() {';
  echo 'location.replace("https://www.yoursite.com");';
  echo '}';
  echo '</script>';
  echo '<div>';
  echo '<p>The record ' . $id . ' is deleted.</p>';
  echo '<button onclick="backToIndex()">ok</button>';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

If you want the user to confirm before you delete, you can store a timestamp or random string in a session variable and check, if it is set. If not, ask for confirmation. If it is set, delete.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
  $id = $_GET['del'];
  if (!isset($_SESSION['del_confirmed'])) {
    $_SESSION['del_confirmed'] = microtime();
  }
  if ($_GET['token'] === $_SESSION['del_confirmed']) {
    mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM info WHERE id=$id");
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Address deleted!";
    unset($_SESSION['del_confirmed']);
    header('location: index.php');
  } else {
?>

<script>
function backToIndex() {
  location.href= "index.php";
}
</script>

<div>
<p>Do you really want to delete record <?=$id?>?</p>
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="del" value="<?=$id?>">
<input type="text" name="token" value="<?=$_SESSION['del_confirmed']?>">
<button type="submit">yes</button>
</form>
<button onclick="javascript:backToIndex();">no</button>
</div>

<?php
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but  I want to warn (or inform) the user first before deleting the record, for which my next step was to use 'confirm' but alert did not succeed as a test! @Olafant

Comment: This is not how php works. You send data from the server to the client by echoing. If the user is confirming something by clicking, it's a new request to the server. You can't pause the php script and wait for a users response.

Comment: If you want the user to confirm, do it before you send him to the site that will delete the record.

Comment: How would I make confirm and then delete in sequence without issuing these two requests one after the other? Confirm will give the options of deleting or not and then -immediately- if the user confirms, a delete request should be issued..Regards

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Tested and worked for me.

```
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
$id = $_GET['del'];
$alert = 'alert("The record' . $id  .'will be deleted");';
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo $alert;
echo "</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the php first then adding the script tag.
This worked I tried it online

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
        $id = $_GET['del'];
        ?>
       <script>
         alert("The record <?php echo $id ?> will be deleted");
         </script>
       <?php

        mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM info WHERE id=$id");
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Address deleted!";
        header('location: index.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: 1-Thanks for your answer, but even I close my script with a (;) it will not work. 2- I want to warn the user not to dump $id.

Comment: Hi I tried it here: http://phpfiddle.org/ I have edited my code which  worked on my end